Python 3.11 i downloaded the module but its not working pywin32
i tried to download this module named pywin32 and it downloaded but it says no module named win32api i already did it
C:\Users\Maste>pip install pywin32
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32 in c:\users\maste\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (306)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maste\OneDrive\Masaüstü\thecode.txt", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'

import cv2
import os
from mss import mss
import numpy as np
import win32api
import serial
import time
import keyboard
import winsound

os.system("color 5")
os.system("cls")
print("Getting Device Info          ")
print("")
print("Version : 1.3.1              ")
print("")
print("Made with love By Luna       ")
print("")
print("Choose your settings")
print("")

fov = int(input("FOV: "))
print("")

sct = mss()

arduino = serial.Serial('COM6', 115200)

screenshot = sct.monitors[1]
screenshot['left'] = int((screenshot['width'] / 2) - (fov / 2))
screenshot['top'] = int((screenshot['height'] / 2) - (fov / 2))
screenshot['width'] = fov
screenshot['height'] = fov
center = fov/2

embaixo = np.array([140,111,160])
emcima = np.array([148,154,194])

speed = float(input("SPEED: "))
print("")
print("You are ready to go ")
print("")
print("Luna wish you a great day <3 ")
print("")
current_time = time.strftime("    %H:%M:%S    ")
print("The time is", current_time)
print("")

def mousemove(x):
    if x < 0:
        x = x+256
    pax = [int(x)]
    arduino.write(pax)
    arduino.read(2)  # Read the mouse movement data back from the Arduino
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, pax[0], 0, 0, 0)  # Move the mouse on the computer

toggle = True

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("f9"):
        toggle = not toggle
        frequency = 1500
        duration = 100
        winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
        print("Toggle is ", toggle)
        time.sleep(1)

    if toggle:
        img = np.array(sct.grab(screenshot))
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, embaixo,emcima)
        kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
        dilated = cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations= 5)
        thresh = cv2.threshold(dilated, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        if len(contours) != 0:
            mouse = cv2.moments(thresh)
            pixel = (int(mouse["m10"] / mouse["m00"]), int(mouse["m01"] / mouse["m00"]))
            aimzao = pixel[0] + 2
            diff_x = int(aimzao - center)
            alvo = diff_x * speed
        mousemove(alvo)

    #performance delay
    time.sleep(0.01)


Are you sure the python executable you are using is the same one that pip is pointing to?  Check where pip and where python

Also give this a look over https://discuss.python.org/t/cannot-successfully-install-win32api/19695

i don't get it is there a more good answer ? say step by step

What is the output of pip show pywin32?

I noticed that you're using win32api to move the mouse in your code, instead, you can use a different module such as pynput or pyautogui which fixes the problem for this code.
Here's an example with pyautogui:
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100) #moves the mouse to screen coordinates (100, 100)

It's pretty simple. I did notice a few things in your code that can be improved, for example, the while True: loop checking for keyboard.is_pressed() is slightly inefficient, here's a better way using keyboard.hotkey():
#all code above the statement "toggle = True" goes here

class Toggle:
    def __init__(self, frequency, duration, embaixo, emcima, speed):
        self.toggle = True
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.duration = duration
        self.embaixo = embaixo
        self.emcima = emcima
        self.speed = speed

        keyboard.add_hotkey('f9', self.onPress)
    
    def onPress(self):
        self.toggle = not self.toggle
        winsound.Beep(self.frequency, self.duration)
        print("Toggle is ", self.toggle)
        time.sleep(1)

        if self.toggle:
            img = np.array(sct.grab(screenshot))
            hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
            mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, self.embaixo, self.emcima)
            kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)
            dilated = cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations= 5)
            thresh = cv2.threshold(dilated, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
            contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            if len(contours) != 0:
                mouse = cv2.moments(thresh)
                pixel = (int(mouse["m10"] / mouse["m00"]), int(mouse["m01"] / mouse["m00"]))
                aimzao = pixel[0] + 2
                diff_x = int(aimzao - center)
                alvo = diff_x * self.speed
            mousemove(alvo)

        time.sleep(0.01)

Toggle(1500, 100, embaixo, emcima, speed)

This code works so every time you press 'f9', the function that was bound to the hotkey is called, and the variable self.toggle is negated. Then, in that same function, we check if now self.toggle is True, and do the required actions if it is. This code is probably more efficient than using a while True loop.
If you want to learn more about pyautogui or pynput, then here's the link to the docs for both:
pyautogui
pynput

pywin32 should be available by default on your operating system, try upgrading first,
python -m pip install --upgrade pywin32

and if you still have issues, try
python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install

